# How do a specify the color of a specific table row in an external CSS file?

Tags: html, css, background-color, css-tables

I am trying to change the color of each row. I already have the external CSS file linked to the HTML file.

HTML file:

```
<tr><div class="row1">
    <td>15</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>30</td>
</div></tr>


<tr><div class="row2">
    <td>45</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>45</td>
</div></tr>


<tr><div class="row3">
    <td>60</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>90</td>
 </div></tr>
```

In my CSS I do this:

```
    .row1{
        background-color: hotpink;
    }
    .row2{
        background-color: #ff0000;
    }
    .row3{
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

Comment: Div inside a tr is invalid HTML. Use the TR instead

Comment: Just remove DIV and its done :)

Answer (score 2):

Give the class to the `<tr>` tags instead:

```css
.row1 {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
.row2 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.row3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row1">
    <td>15</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row2">
    <td>45</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>45</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row3">
    <td>60</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>90</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the class on the `tr` directly

```css
.row1 {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
.row2 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.row3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row1">
    <td>15</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row2">
    <td>45</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>45</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row3">
    <td>60</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>90</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use DIVS inside tr element. Do like this:

```
<tr class="row1">
    <td>15</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>30</td>
</tr>

<tr class="row2">
    <td>45</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>45</td>
</tr>


<tr class="row3">
    <td>60</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>90</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this with pseudo selector

```css
table tr:first-child{background-color: hotpink;}
table tr:nth-child(2){background-color: #ff0000;}
table tr:nth-child(3){background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr >
    <td>15</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>30</td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>45</td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>90</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```